# Javascript match line with pattern and line after

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm trying to implement a functionality similar to pcregrep -A1 in Unix or grep -A1 in Linux, that finds the line that matches your pattern and the next line after it.

For example, let's say we have this text:

```
5000a72b30085ad3 0x4865   22 6 Gb/s  SAS Yes  No   No   No   No
 0   T/D   0 0 0x0 Path: pp0d.20.16
   DISCOVER response: fffff602aa508550::print smp_discover_resp_t
5000a72b30085af7 0x4866   23 6 Gb/s  SAS Yes  No   No   No   No
 0   T/D   0 0 0x0 Path: pp0d.20.17
   DISCOVER response: fffff602aa508738::print smp_discover_resp_t
0000000000000000    N/A   24    N/A None No   No   No   No   No
   0   T/D   0 0 0x0 Path: pp0d.20.18
0000000000000000    N/A   25    N/A None No   No   No   No   No
```

I want it to find all those lines that have a valid WWN (not 0000000000000000    ) and don't have N/A, and also return the line right after it:

```
5000a72b30085ad3 0x4865   22 6 Gb/s  SAS Yes  No   No   No   No
  0   T/D   0 0 0x0 Path: pp0d.20.16    
5000a72b30085af7 0x4866   23 6 Gb/s  SAS Yes  No   No   No   No
 0   T/D   0 0 0x0 Path: pp0d.20.17
```

I can get so far as to matching the line with the correct WWN, but I don't know how to get the line after...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want something like in grep but in javascript, there is no point in tagging as grep. Removing that tag.

Comment: Am I supposed to know what a "valid WWN" means? I think I can gather from the "don't have N/A" - but make it easy for me...

Comment: @ClasG I added more info. I know how to grep the line, I don't know how to catch the line after as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not beautiful, but works:

```
^\s*(?!0{16})\w{16}\s(?:.(?!N\/A))*$\n.*
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7oN4/4).

Note! If you need to capture the match, add parentheses:

```
^\s(?!0{16})(\w{16}\s(?:.(?!N\/A))*$\n.*)
```

**Edit:** Changed to allow for optional initial spaces.

Comment: Any reason you choose to write 16 zeros, and not just a range meta sequence: `0{16}`?

Comment: I've just tested it against a new set of lines and it didn't work, see https://regex101.com/r/lZ7oN4/2

Comment: @andlrc Absolutely not :P Just I copied and pasted to **not** have to count them :D LAZY!

Comment: That's because you changed the conditions. [Check this and it'll work](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7oN4/4)

Comment: @ClasG, one more question: if I want the WWN to end in f and have it always search for SAS and ignore the rest? :) just to filter it even more...

Comment: Hmm... It would have been a lot easier for me (us) if I had all the info from start. `^\s*\w{15}f.*SAS.*\n.*` -  [Check here](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7oN4/5)